# Can an open cup attenuate radio waves as well as a Faraday cage?

Tags: electricity, radio

The problem is that thieves in my neighborhood are using a power amplifier to increase the "bubble distance" of my car so that it thinks that my key fob, which is sitting in my house, is next to the car, thus unlocking the doors.

I've been keeping my keys in a metal box at night.

I'm trying to remember back to my E&M days. I'm sure a metal box is an effective Faraday cage, but it would be more convenient to leave the lid off, or use a cup.

How can I figure out how much attenuation I would get from an open container, and in what direction, specifically at 315MHz and 433.92 MHz?

Comment: I calculated that 300MHz should be attenuated by a Faraday cage with holes smaller than ~5cm. So would a <5 cm diameter metal cup work?

Comment: The attenuation of a waveguide with a dimension smaller than a wavelength increases exponentially with the length of the waveguide and that's the effect a lot of commercial microwave attenuators use. A tall can should do the job.